# GNU tar how to preserve file immutable attribute set by "chattr +i" in Linux?

Tags: linux, backup, tar

I want use tar(GNU tar 1.30) to backup files with immutable attribute set by "chattr +i" in Linux. Command lines below:

```
mdx@e5450:~$ touch test.txt
mdx@e5450:~$ sudo chattr +i test.txt
mdx@e5450:~$ lsattr test.txt
----i---------e---- test.txt
mdx@e5450:~$ sudo tar --acls --selinux --xattrs --xattrs-include='*' -cpvvzf test.tar.gz test.txt
-rw-r--r--  mdx/mdx           0 2024-03-01 16:30 test.txt
mdx@e5450:~$ mkdir test
mdx@e5450:~$ sudo tar --acls --selinux --xattrs --xattrs-include='*' -xpvvzf test.tar.gz -C test
-rw-r--r--  mdx/mdx           0 2024-03-01 16:30 test.txt
mdx@e5450:~$ lsattr test/test.txt
--------------e---- test/test.txt
mdx@e5450:~$
```

You see, the immutable attribute is gone after extracting.

I can use bsdtar 3.3.3 archive test.txt, the immutable attribute will be preserved. Detail below:

```
mdx@e5450:~$ sudo bsdtar -cvvzf test.btar.gz test.txt
a -rw-r--r--  1 mdx    mdx         0 Mar  1 16:30 test.txt
mdx@e5450:~$ mkdir btest
mdx@e5450:~$ sudo bsdtar -xvvzf test.btar.gz -C btest
x -rw-r--r--  0 mdx    mdx         0 Mar  1 16:30 test.txt
mdx@e5450:~$ lsattr btest/test.txt
----i---------e---- btest/test.txt
```

Is it possible preserve file immutable attribute set by "chattr +i" when using GNU tar in Linux?

Comment: Submit a bug report - looking at the man-page it **should** work, it obviously doesn't for you (what filesystem are you using, btw?) and I just tried on ext4 w/ no luck.

Comment: You can't unless you wanna write a a script for that and store this info separately, e.g. in a text file. A Linux only, an ext4 only flag with no kernel syscall? Nah, I don't think tar will consider adding support for it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov these kind of attributes are just called "flags" on bsd / Darwin. And them being ext only is a bit of a 1990s problem; by now, most Linux-supported "fully fledged" file systems from xfs (the oldest) to btrfs support things like the immutable flag/attr

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov and to be quite honest, GNU core utilities support such a wealth of obscure features, I don't think tar supporting important file properties is a "won't even consider" thing.

Comment: @tink kernel 5.15.*, tested both ext4 and btrfs, same result.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Using a script to restore these attributes is a way. But it is not a good choice in some situation, e.g., I don't know which files are set by chattr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've found a shortcoming in GNU tar. But it's not like you think!

The "i" is what is called a "attribute" in Linux file system lingo. Now, you're correctly saving and restoring *extended attributes*, a much later addition, but not the old-school *attributes*.

Sadly, GNU tar has no command line option to enforce these, and doesn't seem to consistently handle them. The fact that bsdtar indeed does correctly do that indicates there's a bug or a feature shortcoming. My bet is that it's simply not implemented, because I couldn't quickly find an `ioctl` on `FS_IMMUTABLE_FL` in the GNU tar source code. Shouldn't be too much of an addition - do send an email to their mailing list asking whether this is intended!

Comment: Sadly this is an extended well thought out comment but not an answer.

Comment: @sina bala Yes. It should be a shortcoming. I post a bug onto gnu-tar: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?65397

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Q is: "how do I make GNU tar do what I need?" My answer: "Get it fixed upstream"

Comment: Which is already stated in my comment above ;)

Comment: @tink you're right :) but I took the time to get the source code and actually look for any sign of the functionality, found none, and thus felt like I could actually on good authority write this as an answer :)

Comment: It seems no better answer about this. Any news about this question I will post here.

Comment: I posted this question on bug-tar mailing list, Paul Eggert, one of maintainer of tar project, answered: The attributes we're talking about are inode flags (see "man ioctl_iflags"). There is no tar command line option to preserve attributes set by chattr and no current plan to implement this though it'd be nice to have such a feature.

Comment: Paul Eggert is also very involved in gnulib and Coreutils, so great to have his view on things!